# where can find sample coding for use of Bouncy Castle(java)?

Tags: cryptography, encryption, java

I had found `bcprov-ext-jdk16-145.jar` and `bcprov-jdk16-145.zip`. I wish to use the IDEA encryption to encrypt XML, but I haven't found any sample of coding in JAVA.

Can anyone tell me how to call the methods in `org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.symmetric.*` to do the IDEA encryption and decryption or where can find sample code?

Comment: this question doesn't look like a security question in its current form, more like a programming question. You may get some answers here, however you may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Rory, I'm not so sure - code for performing encryption *is* ontopic, I think... That said, for something this niche, he's likely to get answers quicker. However, I've noticed programmers often use cryptographic functions *wrong* (like, using the wrong cipher mode, getting the padding wrong, etc.)

Comment: @AviD @Rory I agree with AviD. I don't have enough experience to answer this question, but it'd definitely be better to ask security people this question than programmers.

Answer (score 1):

BouncyCastle is a standard JCE provider, so most Java crypto code will work just fine. You just need to add the provider to java.security...  security.provider.6=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
I'd recommend using something like OWASP ESAPI instead of using the crypto API directly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have special IDEA sample code, but there are some samples on the net for symmetric encryption with bouncy castle. Try [this one](http://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/30/07645963/DOWNLOAD/beg_crypto_examples.zip) from the book Beginning Cryptography with Java.